# React-How to display make objects loop in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml, rss

Here is what i tried

`episode.js`

```js
import Parser from "rss-parser";
import React from "react";

export default function Episode() {
  
const parser = new Parser();
const url1 = "https://anchor.fm/s/75abc654/podcast/rss";
const [data, setData] = React.useState({});
 
 (async  () => {
    let data = await parser.parseURL(url1);
  setData(data);
   // console.log(data.title)
   // data.items.forEach((item) => {
      // console.log(item.title)
      //console.log(item.pubDate.slice(5, 17))
      //console.log(item.enclosure.url)
      // console.log(item.itunes.image)
    });
  })();
return(
  <h1>{item.title}</h1>

  {data.items.map((item, index)=>{
  return(
     <h1>{item.title}</h1>
   )})}

)

}
```

And the output is blank screen.. No error in console.. Help me to get the data from the rss feed without blank screen

Comment: Try using useEffect hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `async` method unlimited time! You need to call it once via `useEffect` just when component rendered for first time:

```
import Parser from "rss-parser"; 
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function Episode() {
  const parser = new Parser();
  const url1 = "https://anchor.fm/s/75abc654/podcast/rss";
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let data = await parser.parseURL(url1);
      console.log(data);
      setData(data);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {data.items?.map((item, index) => (
        <h1>{item.title}</h1>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return <Episode />;
}
```

[image: Edit nervous-pasteur-z6xu9]

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your async function with a `useEffect` hook like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchMyAPI() {
    let data = await parser.parseURL(url1);
    setData(data);
    // console.log(data.title)
    // data.items.forEach((item) => {
    // console.log(item.title)
    //console.log(item.pubDate.slice(5, 17))
    //console.log(item.enclosure.url)
    // console.log(item.itunes.image)
  }
  fetchMyAPI();
}, []);
```

This will be executed once every time when your component is loaded on screen

Also change the `data.item.map` to

```
{data.items?.map((item, index) => {
    return <h1>{item.title}</h1>;
 })}
```

Else it will throw error on first render